# t-SNE output graph rotation/flip/transformation

Tags: data-visualization, dimensionality-reduction, tsne

As I understand it, the output of a t-SNE graph has arbitrary axis directions. That is, the axis can be easily flipped by multiplying one/both of the output coordinates by -1, and the output graph can still be visually interpreted equally validly.

[This article](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3574019/), in section "Materials and Methods" > "PCA vs. t-SNE", describes t-SNE as using a "method/optimization-criteria [that] is rotation and scale-invariant", which suggests that t-SNE outputs can also be rotated by, say, 45 degrees in either direction. This could be carried out by any algorithm for rotation about a point.

Is this accurate, and if so, does it matter which point is chosen as the center of rotation of a t-SNE map?

Answer (score 3):

tSNE is an embedding in lower dimensions (say 2,3) which tries to preserve distances, in this case distances being represented by probabilities. Note that you don't really care about the resulting orientation. You only care to see which clusters of points are close to each other and which are far away. If you look at the points upside-down your conclusion will be the same.

Perhaps you could elaborate more on your question but, the result is rotation invariant so long as your distance function is rotationally invariant. Scale invariance is not completely guaranteed, unless you're normalizing your coordinates in a predefined way: there's a notion of perplexity in tSNE which is a hyperparameter that tunes the bandwidth of Gaussians used to define the above probabilities, and keeping this parameter fixed while changing scale will likely give you a different embedding.